# Truncating table with keyword as name

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, junit

I've been having this convenience problem which I can't seem to tackle. My table called `Plan` won't truncate.
The table entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`Plan`")
public class TablePlan {
    ...
}
```

And in between unit tests I need to truncate this table:

```
@After
public void resetDatabase(){
    EntityManager em = objectRegistration.getEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    em.createNativeQuery("truncate table Plan").executeUpdate();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Since `Plan` is a keyword in MSSQL, I needed to surround "Plan" with back quotes as you can see at the entity table name. I'm currently just using hibernate to test my methods, which doesn't require me to surround "Plan" with back quotes, but as this code is intended for an actual database, I do not want to change it.

I also cannot change any names anywhere, as this is an existing database with milions of entries.

I already tried to truncate it like this:

```
em.createNativeQuery("truncate table `Plan`").executeUpdate();
```

But this doesn't seem to work and after an hour of searching the web and not knowing exactly what to search, I figured let's use this SO account for a change! I've already debugged the code to the point where I am 100% certain the truncate update query simply does not execute because it truncates some non-existing table. Hence my "Plan" table isn't recognized.

If you need more information I will try to provide it here.

Thanks in advance for reading this =)

*****SOLUTION*****

Change the table name:

```
@Table(name = "\"Plan\"")
```

And change the truncate query:

```
em.createNativeQuery("truncate table \"Plan\"").executeUpdate();
```

Et voila!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A back quote is not an escape character in SQL Server.

In SQL Server, table names that don't conform to the rules for regular identifiers (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx) must to be enclosed in either square brackets or double quotes.  Double-quotes is the ANSI standard enclosure.

Comment: You are correct. I only added the back quotes because I was told somewhere else this would fix my sql problems. Used double quotes now and unit tests are running again. Still need to test my mssql server, whether that still works as well =)

Comment: Works on mssql as well, thanks! Will update my code in the question

Comment: FWIW JDBC DatabaseMetadata has a method that tells you what to quote things with, so you can become database independent.

Comment: Another remark: backticks are still correct in the `@Table` annotation, as defined in the JPA spec - they are replaced to the `"` by the JPA provider.